# Saying Asher Yatzar after Hamapil

Tags: halacha, sleep, bathroom, asher-yatzar, hamapil

If you say the bracha of Hamapil then you have to go bathroom, after you go bathroom are you permitted to say the bracha?

Why yes or why no?

Source?

Comment: Why might you think that one cannot say that blessing then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are allowed.Kitzur Shulchan Aruch says so. You do not repeat shema or hamapil. Sh"t Yechave data 4:21, Sh"t Tzitz Eliezer 7:27, Sh"t beer Moshe 1:63.

If you forget to say maariv or kidush levana. You can wake up to say the say them both. You do not repeat the Beracha either.

Do not repeat anything if you have to say asher yatzar. Normally, a yid (Jew) who is yiras shamayim should make sure he does not have to use the bathroom before sleeping and davening.

Please ask more questions if you would like.

Comment: Re the 3rd paragraph - Are you sure you have that correctly? I thought O.C. states that one should not daven (Amidah esp.) when one needs to use the restroom. I.e., one **should** use the rest room prior to davening so that he needn't go during davening. As for nighttime shema - people over 50, inevitably, will probably be using the restroom after *Shema* but before the time for *Shacahrit* Shema.

Comment: Where does Kitzur Shulchan Aruch say this?

Answer (score 0):

Rav Shlomo Zalmen Aurbach ZTL, quoted in Halichos Shlomo 13:24; Shailos Utshuvos Yisa Yosef vol. 4 #55 quoting Rav YS Elyashiv ZTL; and Shailos Utshuvos Rivivos Ephraim vol.1 #180 all say that one should say the bracha on thunder and lightning when heard after bedtime krias Shema.