# Speech After Recitation of HaMapil

Tags: blessing, speech-talking, sleep, hefsek-interruption, hamapil

What do halachic sources say regarding speech after the nocturnal blessing of HaMapil?

Of particular (but not exclusive) interest are the earliest sources that prohibit speech after the recitation.

---

Related: [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44298/saying-asher-yatzar-after-hamapil) which addresses specific speech after HaMapil.

Comment: Parallel question: What do halachic sources say regarding speech before the morning blessing of HaMaavir?

Comment: The only Rishon I'm aware of who discusses speaking after HaMapil is the Avudraham who summarily rejects a prohibition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [@gershongold 's link](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/18363), the Rema (Orach Chaim 239: 2) writes:

> וְיִקְרָא קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע סָמוּךְ לְמִטָּתוֹ, וְאֵין אוֹכְלִים וְשׁוֹתִים וְלֹא מְדַבְּרִים אַחַר קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע שֶׁעַל מִטָּתוֹ, אֶלָּא יִישַׁן מִיָּד

That is, after reciting kriyat shma in bed one doesn't eat, drink, or speak, but rather sleeps immediately.

Also cited are the Beit Yosef citing the Kol Bo who writes the same, and the Rokeach who shared this view.

It should be noted that they are addressing speaking after the nocturnal kriyat Sh'ma; not after HaMapil. Magen Avraham (239:2), however, does write that breaking after HaMapil is a problem.

However,also cited is the view of the Aruch Hashulchan, that there is no prohibition whatsoever in making a *hefsek* (separation) between the blessing of HaMapil, and falling asleep.

Comment: Why is anything before the word "Magen" here at all?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because I mistakenly conflated them to start with, and while technically distinct, they seem similar enough to be warrant inclusion (as this fills the answer meaningfully, IMHO, for anyone interested in the matter).

Comment: I tend to think it's presenting them as related which has led to anyone thinking talking is prohibited. The ShA puts HaMappil last, but the Rama's quote comes from the Kol Bo who put HaMappil first. But for those who just read the ShA and Mappah, look what happens...

Comment: @DoubleAA agreed. Maybe if I have time I will clarify.