# Speaking 30 minutes after hamapil

Tags: halacha, blessing, sleep, hefsek-interruption, hamapil

A person is discouraged from speaking after reciting the blessing of "Hamapil" before bed (Magen Avraham 239 s.v. ומברך המפיל explaining why the SA says to say Hamapil after Kriyas Shema).

Someone told me the purpose is to juxtapose the blessing to falling asleep. Therefore if after 30 minutes you fail to fall asleep, since you failed to make the juxtaposition, you're allowed to speak freely. Is there any basis for this statement? Any sources to back it up?

Comment: -1 for misrepresenting your source. The Rama says not to speak after Shema, not Hamapil. There is no classical source in Rishonim for not speaking after Hamapil, and a number of Rishonim even explicitly permit it.

Comment: Fine, I read that into the Rema. The Magen Avraham says it explicitly, so I fixed it

Comment: Perhaps none of the Rishonim discuss this question but for all I know one of the Achronim do, which is why I asked here, since I don't know

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60344/speech-after-recitation-of-hamapil