# Talking after Hamapil blessing

Tags: blessing, sleep, hamapil

It is customary to say the *hamapil* blessing before going to sleep at night. Some people are strict in saying this nightly, some are more lax. I don't know if this has any halachic source.

- Is there a reason many people don't say this beracha?
- Is it permitted to talk after the beracha? [Idle chatter? Saying good night to a spouse or roommate? Important conversation?]
- If one has reason to assume they will need to talk after the blessing, should they still make the blessing

All sources about customs or halachos regarding this blessing are appreciated.

Comment: Also [Saying Asher Yatzar after Hamapil](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44298/6592)

Comment: Also why be ShevaYipol when you could be TzaddikVekom?

Comment: @Shmosel: So true :)